# Get javascript variable's value in Django url template tag

Tags: javascript, django, url

It is known that there's a DRY way of directing to an URL by using django template tag "url", say

```
{% url "someview" arg1=X %}
```

Here, I want "X" to be the value of a javascript variable, say `tmp`. But the following doesn't work

```
<script>
    ...{% url "someview" arg1=tmp %}...
</script>
```

How should I get the value inside a template tag?

Comment: You could try: `{% url 'someview' %}?arg1=tmp`

Comment: Are you sure this is right? It seems there's some grammar mistake.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot that `tmp` is javascript variable, so:
`<script>
  var href = '{% url 'someview' %}?arg1=' + tmp; 
</script>`

Comment: I'm afraid it's still not working. Django urls don't work in this way. Say my "someview" url is like "^(?P<arg1>\d+)/somethingelse...$"

Comment: @Marii that works only if you're using get parameters, not with post

Answer (score 97, accepted):

I found a trick that might work under most circumstances:

```
var url_mask = "{% url 'someview' arg1=12345 %}".replace(/12345/, tmp.toString());
```

It's clean, and it doesn't break DRY principle.

Comment: Neat idea - worth noting that this'll only work if `arg1` can be numeric, and if the reversed URL doesn't contain other instances of the string "/12345/".

Comment: @DominicRodger the value 12345 is just a placeholder of sorts, if the reversed URL did contain that placeholder, it would suffice to change it for something that isn't there. Why wouldn't it work if arg1 can't be numeric?

Comment: I have tried this but nothing is working in my case, it recognizes url before replacement taken place.  "var url_mask = "{% url 'someview' pk=12345 %}".replace(/12345/, "1");"

Comment: I have tried with App name and using django 1.11, its not working, var href = "{% url 'Myaap:report_page' args1=0 %}".replace(/0/, temp_location.toString())

Comment: I did like this & it worked for me, `var url_mask = "{% url 'someview' 12345 %}".replace(/12345/, tmp.toString());`

Answer (score 18):

Just making it clear so next readers can have a comprehensive solution. In regard to the question, this is how I used Mike Lee solution for an example case which is redirecting with Javascript to a new page with a parameter in a variable named **tmp**:

```
window.location = "{% url 'your_view_name' 1234 %}".replace(/1234/, tmp.toString());
```

Comment: What exactly has to go in my html template?

Comment: @MeL It all depends on what you are trying to accomplish. What is it in your case?

Comment: It didn't work for me until putting 1234 between single quotes: '1234'.

Answer (score 2):

one easy way to do this is

```
<div id="test" style="display: none;">
 {% url 'some_url:some_sub_url'%}
</div>


<script>
  url_mask = $( "#test" ).html()
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var name = "{% url 'your_view_name' pk=0 %}".replace('0', name_variable);
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar solution with `concat` instead of `replace`, so you avoid the `id` clash:

```
var pre_url = "{% url 'topology_json' %}";
var url = pre_url.concat(tool_pk, '/', graph_depth, '/');
```

But you need a non-parameter url to keep Django pleasant with the `pre_url` because the loading-time evaluation, my `urls.py` is:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^topology_json/$',
        views.topology_json,
        name='topology_json'),
    url(r'^topology_json/(?P<tool_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<depth>[0-9]+)/$',
        views.topology_json,
        name='topology_json'),
    ...
]
```

And parameters in view have suitable default values, so `views.py`:

```
def topology_json(request, tool_id=None, depth=1):                                             
    """                                                                                        
    JSON view returns the graph in JSON format.                
    """                                                                                        
    if tool_id:                                                                                
        tool = get_object_or_404(Tool, pk=tool_id)                                             
        topology = get_graph(str(tool), int(depth))                                            
    else:
        ...
```

Django yet 1.11 here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to use a named argument to `{% url %}` from JavaScript, however you could do a positional argument or querystring parameter:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tmp = window.location.hash, //for example
        url = {% url '[url_name]' %} + tmp + '/';
</script>
```

But, you could only do that once, when the template is initially rendered.

Comment: Yeah, I come up with a similar trick. Something like var url_mask = "{% url 'someview' arg1=12345 %}".replace(/12345/, tmp.toString());

Comment: Cool. You can always answer your own question, which is beneficial for others looking at this question in the future.