# Passing variable through Django template url tag

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I am trying to pass a variable through the Django template url tag with little success.

My path in the urls.py:

`path("viewListing/<int:listingID>", views.bookListing, name="viewListing")`

In the template, I am using javascript to generate the listingID with a for loop.

```
for(j=0; j<5; j++){
  var thisID = (data[j].id)
  imgA.href = "{% url 'viewListing' thisID %}";
}
```

However, I am getting this error

```
Reverse for 'viewListing' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['viewListing/(?P<listingID>[0-9]+)$']
```

If I pass a number instead of thisID, for instance 1, the code works fine.

So my question is, how can I make this work with a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use django tags inside Javascript. They are server side. What you can do instead is cache the url in a variable and then concatenate the ID to it like this:

```
for(j=0; j<5; j++){
    var thisID = (data[j].id)
    var listing_url = "{% url 'viewListing' listingID=9999 %}";
    imgA.href = listing_url.replace(/9999/, thisID);
}
```

Credit goes to @MikeLee:
[Get javascript variable's value in Django url template tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832194/get-javascript-variables-value-in-django-url-template-tag)