# How to pass a variable from javascript into url through href: django

Tags: django, href, url-parameters

I have seen various post allowing user to do this by including the var as part of the url something like this
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/?var1="var1"+var2="var2"`

But in my case I need to send the variable into href tag which goes to views function in my django app
`<a href="{% url 'process-payment'>` 
I have the variable set like this:

```
<td><strong>Rs.<span id="totalPrice">{{ order.get_cart_total}}</span></strong></td>
.
.
<a href="{% url 'process-payment'> 
.
<script>
    var totalPrice = document.getElementById("totalPrice").innerHTML;   //picking a value through innerHTML
</script>
```

Can anyone help me build this url so the value goes to views function

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns=[
path('payment/',views.process_payment, name='process-payment'),
]
```

Comment: Does this help?


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832194/get-javascript-variables-value-in-django-url-template-tag

Comment: No it didn't work for me, need some better solution. Even in the page the solution provided is not satisfying to others.

Comment: Did you close the <a> tag? It seems like you left it open, it should be:
<a href="{% url 'process-payment' %}"></a>