# NoReverseMatch at /v2/search/SARS_CoV_2/GID1716

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am developing a django application in which I am trying to send a value of the variable to the backend  on click of a button through javascript.

javascript code:

```
$(document).on("click", "#filter", function (e) {
      IUPredscorethreshold = 0.4
      $("#ksNetwork").empty();
      ksInteractionNetwork('{% url "camkinetv2:newinteractors_intnet" tab1.caMKipedia_Id IUPredscorethreshold %}');
 });
```

urls.py

```
path(
        "dataJson/newinteractors_intnet/<str:geneId>/<str:IUPredscorethreshold>",
        views.newinteractors_intnet,
        name="newinteractors_intnet",
    ),
```

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def newinteractors_intnet(request, geneId, IUPredscorethreshold):

    print("IUPredscorethreshold:" + IUPredscorethreshold)

.
.
.
.
.
some computation


    graphData = {"nodes": uniquenodesdata, "links": linksdata}

    response = JsonResponse(graphData)

    return response
```

when I execute this code i am getting following error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /v2/search/SARS_CoV_2/GID1716
Reverse for 'newinteractors_intnet' with arguments '('GID1716', '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['v2/dataJson/newinteractors_intnet/(?P<geneId>[^/]+)/(?P<IUPredscorethreshold>[^/]+)$']
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'newinteractors_intnet' with arguments '('GID1716', '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['v2/dataJson/newinteractors_intnet/(?P<geneId>[^/]+)/(?P<IUPredscorethreshold>[^/]+)$']
```

what am I doing wrong? how can I solve this issue. I am still at learning stage of django and I am not able to figure out how to solve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says it couldn't find a url that matches `{% url "camkinetv2:newinteractors_intnet" tab1.caMKipedia_Id IUPredscorethreshold %}`. Your urls.py declares `IUPredscorethreshold` to be a string by putting `str:` in front of it. In your javascript you assign `0.4` to that variable which is an integer. Therefore, the url you doesn’t resolve.

Change your path in urls.py to:
`path( "dataJson/newinteractors_intnet/<str:geneId>/<int:IUPredscorethreshold>", views.newinteractors_intnet, name="newinteractors_intnet", ),`

Comment: I had made changes to urls.py file but still getting the error: 
`Reverse for 'newinteractors_intnet' with arguments '('GID1716', '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['v2/dataJson/newinteractors_intnet/(?P<geneId>[^/]+)/(?P<IUPredscorethreshold>[0-9]+)$'] `

Comment: moreover what I have observed is, if i change my javascript line from `ksInteractionNetwork('{% url "camkinetv2:newinteractors_intnet" tab1.caMKipedia_Id IUPredscorethreshold %}');`  to  `ksInteractionNetwork('{% url "camkinetv2:newinteractors_intnet" tab1.caMKipedia_Id "IUPredscorethreshold" %}')` i.e. putting `IUPredscorethreshold in "IUPredscorethreshold"` i am not getting any error but in my views.py when I print it I am getting it  variable not the value `IUPredscorethreshold:IUPredscorethreshold`

Answer (score 0):

Change your Javascript code to this:

```
$(document).on("click", "#filter", function (e) {
  IUPredscorethreshold = 0.4
  $("#ksNetwork").empty();
  let url = '{% url "camkinetv2:newinteractors_intnet" ' + tab1.caMKipedia_Id + ' ' + IUPredscorethreshold + '%}'
  ksInteractionNetwork(url);
});
```

I believe that the url is not forming correctly

Comment: I had changed the javascript but I am still getting an error: 
`
 Reverse for 'newinteractors_intnet' with arguments '(' + tab1.caMKipedia_Id + ', ' + IUPredscorethreshold + ')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['v2/dataJson/newinteractors_intnet/(?P<geneId>[^/]+)/(?P<IUPredscorethreshold>[0-9]+)$']
`

Answer (score 0):

changing javascript line from:`ksInteractionNetwork('{% url "camkinetv2:newinteractors_intnet" tab1.caMKipedia_Id IUPredscorethreshold %}');`  to `ksInteractionNetwork('{% url "camkinetv2:newinteractors_intnet" tab1.caMKipedia_Id "IUPredscorethreshold" %}'.replace(/IUPredscorethreshold/, IUPredscorethresholdvalues) );`

following answer helped [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46877071/6740219)