# How to configure a django url correctly in javascript

Tags: javascript, django

I have seen lots of questions and answers on this topic (e.g.[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832194/get-javascript-variables-value-in-django-url-template-tag)), but the solution seems to evade me. In my template I have a series of radio buttons and wish to pass the selected item back to the view

**common/urls.py**

```
path('use-selected/<str:app_base>/<str:board_number>/', views.UseSelectedItem.as_view(), name='use-selected'),
```

If I enter the the following code in my template, it works correctly

```
<a id="use-selected" href="{% url 'use-selected' app_base='solo' board_number='4' %}"><button type="submit">Use selected</button></a>
```

if, on the other hand, I assign the href in javascript

**html**

```
<a id="use-selected" href=""><button type="submit">Use selected</button></a>
```

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    selectedBoard = document.getElementsByName('selected_board_id');
    use_selected_href = document.getElementById('use-selected-href');
    selectedBoard.forEach((radioButton) => {
        radioButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            processBoardSelection(radioButton.value)
        });
    })
});

function processBoardSelection(board_number) {
    var use_selected_text = "{% url 'use-selected' app_base='app_base_value' board_number='board_number_value' %}"

    temp_text = use_selected_text.replace('board_number_value', board_number.toString());
    use_selected_href.href = href_text;
    // use_selected_href.href="{% url 'use-selected' app_base='solo' board_number='4' %}"
}
```

the link fails. The request url is

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/common/history/solo/%7B%25%20url%20'use-selected'%20app_base%3D'solo'%20board_number%3D'4'%20%25%7D
```

I do not understand where the *common/history/solo* elements arise. *common* and *solo* are apps within my project; *common/history* was the url to get to this page

[EDIT 20210808 08:51 UCT] I have built a simple test app based on this problem and it works correctly. It uses the javascript and the *a* tag in the template as presented here (the java script being in s separate file). The url is interpreted correctly and the parameters are passed to the view.

I repeat :

*I do not understand where the *common/history/solo* elements arise.*

in the url that fails

Comment: Is this inside a separate Javascript file? The Django template language only applies to HTML template files that you've told Django to render. It looks like you've got that literal template-language string as your URL, so the browser is URL-encoding it and using it as a relative URL (as it will with any random strings it is told to use as a URL).

Comment: Going off of what @RobinZigmond said, the best you can do in Javascript is the use template literals (backtick key) to format your URL with variables. See this article for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: It is a separate js file .So how can I pass variables as parameters in the url? I have enhanced my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, as @Robin Zigmond suggested in a comment, that the url creation code works if it is in the template, but not in a separate file. I do not know why because I have used the method of separate files in other applications.

So the template now includes:

```
<a id="use-selected" href=""><button type="submit">Use selected</button></a>
...
<script>
    function processBoardSelection(board_number) {
        var use_selected_text = "{% url 'use-selected' app_base='app_base_value' board_number='board_number_value' %}"
        var use_selected_href = document.getElementById('use-selected');

        temp_text = use_selected_text.replace('board_number_value', board_number.toString());
        href_text = temp_text.replace('app_base_value', app_base.toString());
        use_selected_href.href = href_text;
    }
</script>
```

The rest of the code remains in a separate *js* file

Answer (score 1):

In your template you can try something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="use-selected" value="{% url 'use-selected' app_base='solo' board_number='4' %}">
```

In js code refactor your functions like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // ...
    selectedBoard.forEach((radioButton) => {
        radioButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            href = $("#use-selected").prop("value")
            processBoardSelection(radioButton.value, href)
        });
    })
});


function processBoardSelection(board_number, href) {
    // ...
}
```

There is many methods to get the url.

Comment: Sorry. I'm missing something. I don't understand. This seems to do nothing. What does the hidden element do?