# How to combine javascript modules with javascript code in html

Tags: javascript, html

In my application I have my javascript in files. I am trying to convert those files to javascript modules.

I need to have some code in my html (in order to generate Django urls - (see this question [How to configure a django url correctly in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68693393/how-to-configure-a-django-url-correctly-in-javascript)).

**html**

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="display_text">aaa</p>
    </body>

    <script type="">
        function setText(text) {
            var display_text = document.getElementById('display_text');
            display_text.innerText = text;
        }
    </script>
    <script type="" src="module.js"></script>
</html>
```

**module.js**

```
setText('module')
```

This does not seem to work with modules

If I convert the html as follows

```
<script type="module">
    export function setText(text) {
        var display_text = document.getElementById('display_text');
        display_text.innerText = text
    }
</script>
<script type="module" src="module.js"></script>
```

I get the error

> module.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: setText is not defined

If I need to import the *setText* function into *module.js*, how do I do it?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use code from script with type=module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49338193/how-to-use-code-from-script-with-type-module)

Comment: @Ouroborus I don't think it's quite the same. I understand the need to import, but how can I import a function from an HTML page?

Comment: Yes it seems you have to import from a file. There is import by name or ID as far as I can see. Maybe that means you can only put modules in files. [MDN docs: javascript modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules)

Comment: You can only import into or export from modules. Use a global scope (such as `window.something`) to share data between modules and non-modules. For example, from within the module, `window.setText = setText;`. (Also, modules can't be inlined. They need to be a separate file and you need to be using `https`.) Ideally, you're using all modules or no modules.

Comment: @Ouroborus Yes. Reluctantly I've decided to revert to no modules