# Reverse for 'my_views_name' with no arguments not found. django - jquery , connect server side with client side js

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

i want to make a button to update url. i called data from database using jquery-ajax

this is my views.py

```
def list_maingroup(request):
    lists = MainGroup.objects.all().order_by('-pk')
    data = []
    for i in lists:
        item = {
           'id':i.id,
           'admin':i.admin.username,
           'main_type':i.main_type,
           'date':i.date
        }
        data.append(item)
    return JsonResponse({'data':data})

def update_maingroup(request,id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(MainGroup,id=id)
    form = MainGroupForm(instance=obj)
    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == 'POST' and request.user.is_superuser:
        if form.is_valid():
            form = MainGroupForm(request.POST,instance=object)
            form.save()
            return JsonResponse({'success':'success'})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'success':False,'error_msg':form.errors,'error_code':'invalid'})

    context = {'form':form,'obj':obj}
    return render(request,'update_maingroup.html',context)
```

**my urls.py**

```
path('maingroup/update/<int:id>',update_maingroup,name='update_maingroup'), 
path('list-main-group',list_maingroup,name='list-maingroup'),
```

my form + my model

```
class MainGroup(models.Model):
    admin = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    main_type = models.CharField(max_length=40,unique=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class MainGroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MainGroup
        fields = ['main_type']
```

but it raise this error:

> Reverse for 'update_maingroup' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['maingroup/update/(?P[0-9]+)$']

my templates

```js
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:'/list-main-group',

    success:function(data){

      data = data.data
      spinnerBox.classList.add('non-visible')
      var k = '<tbody>'
      for(i = 0;i < data.length; i++){
        const date = new Date(data[i]["date"]).toLocaleString();
        const id = parseInt(data[i]['id'])
        // const url = '{% url "products:update_maingroup" %}'
        // const my_url = url + "/"+id
        
          k+= '<tr>';
          k+= '<td>' + data[i]['id'] + '</td>';
          k+= '<td>' + data[i]["admin"] + '</td>';
          k+= '<td>' + data[i]["main_type"] + '</td>';
          k+= '<td>' + date + '</td>';
          k+= '<td align="center">'+
            
            '<button class="btn btn-info bg-info"  id="update" data-url='+{% url "products:update_maingroup" id %}+ '><i class="far fa-edit"></i></button>'+
            ' <button class="btn btn-danger btn-del bg-danger" data-did='+parseInt(data[i]["id"])+"><i class='far fa-trash'></i></button>"+

              '</td>';               
          k+= '</tr>'
      }
      k+='</tbody>'
        
      tableBody.innerHTML = k   
          
      $('#maingroupid').dataTable({     
        "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]]
      });
    },
    // error:function(error){
    //   console.log(error)
    // }
   
  });
```

```html
      <div class="card-body table-responsive" >
        <div id="spinner-box" class="spinner-border text-primary text-center" role="status">
        </div>
        <table id="maingroupid" class="table table-bordered table-striped text-center">
        <thead>              
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>{% trans "admin" %}</th>
            <th>{% trans "name" %}</th>
            <th>{% trans "date" %}</th>
            <th>{% trans "options" %}</th>

          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="tableData">

          </tbody>
          </tfoot>
        </table>

      </div>
```

i know, i have to get the id from server, but i dont know where to get it

Comment: How does your urls.py look like? Could it be you forgot to declare the URL that it is looking for?

Comment: @AnnaM added the urls

Comment: Thanks for adding the urls. It seems your current django instance is only aware of one pattern ( 1 pattern(s) tried: ) Could you try to restart and see if it is looking for two patterns?

Comment: shows the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in your code is very subtle and I don't think that Django documentation is really pointing towards this enough.
When commenting out django template code, you absolutely need to use Django formatting. If you use regular formatting (eg. `//` in JavaScript or `<!-- -->` in HTML) the Django syntax will still be executed.

In your code you have the line:

```js
        // const url = '{% url "products:update_maingroup" %}'
```

This url does not exist, as your `update_maingroup` url is defined to always be used with the additional parameter `id`.

I suggest either removing this line or using django formatting when commenting:

```
{# const url = '{% url "products:update_maingroup" %}' #}
```

Edit: Additional info about how to use the correct url from javaScript variables:
Please take a look at this question + answers.
Long story short: there is no real way to do this but people have found ways around it: [Get javaScript variable into url tag.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17832677/10041092)

Comment: so where to put the update url into my js code ? and how to give id to the url ?

Comment: I have expanded my answer. The short answer is there is no real way to do it, only ways around it. And usually you would need to create a url that needs no parameters and use that as a dummy to then update the url. But you can read more about it in the linked answer.